# Android: OpenGL ES: associating information with drawn objects

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a fairly basic question that I cannot for the life of me find the answer to online (most definitely due to not really knowing what I am looking for).

Suppose I have multiple (for the most part static) objects that are stored inside one VBO and drawn to the screen. Each object will have images and text/external data associated with it. I need to be able to navigate this "map" of objects and on-tap, access the corresponding information.

My question is, what is the best practice when it comes to storing this corresponding data and linking it to its respective drawing? I figured you create a "parallel" array of custom objects that each references its drawing and holds all the data... Although it seems quite elementary and thought there might be a better way. Considering also that there will potentially be thousands of these objects on the "map".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can Use model class and put all common data intro one entity than use extends. You can use yours custom object who will consider whole VBO or opengles program data. About identity make ID for each elementary object or "draws".

***-I understand your problematic. In opengl/es procedural programming is actually on scene. 
 Remember you are still in android envelopment you can use any java/android methodology.***

-When you say "tap" did you mean click? If you so than see "Raycast" thema.

-This is interest file . It is JS not android but you can use same logic methods to make your object based app.

https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/visualjs/blob/master/project/project_instance_webgl2/lib/matrix-world.js

You can see lines like this :

App.scene[squareObject.name] = squareObject;

I have a global object App.scene . I put here all object buffer data. It is a key access but works like array.

I wanna say your idea about arrays is good. But not in parallel order. Procedural part works with no problem you need draw function for each element entity.

Look at draw methods :

https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/visualjs/blob/master/project/project_instance_webgl2/lib/matrix-draws.js

For example one of my draw entity is App.operation.draws.cube function.
I use this method to draw any cube but each cube is uniq object with uniq data inside.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply! Thank you for the pointers and examples, I have to chew on this for a bit for I get the broad picture now. One question I have is, when you say you put "all object buffer data" into App.scene, do you mean everything from vertex position to texture, wouldn't that accumulate a lot of memory?

Comment: To clarify, suppose that at any time any of my objects can be changed, keeping all those objects in client side memory seems excessive, do you have any advice for that?

Comment: That's the way how openGL/ES works ( you need loop you can use Runnable() for your draw calling ) . When you need data you must load that data anyway. For example try vertex morphing ( every next draw use different vertex data ) animation and you will see very nice and fluid render. This calling something like Direct memory access. You can delete any "no needed data". Use arrays for containers they you will never have problems with console error logs . Simple slice/remove unwanted element from scene array....

Comment: Thank you once again for you help, I get the picture now